# How to make the home page of a tab-based application a table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard

I am working on a storyboard in Swift. The home page of my app is the reviews feed (see first pic--wireframe) and I need it to be a table view controller so I can display feed data. However, when I have tried adding a tab bar to my table view controller (see second pic--storyboard), it gets placed in-between prototype cells and prototype content. I have also tried adding table view to the home screen, but Swift won't let me add it. Any advice on how to implement my wireframe--whether it be implementing a tab bar at the bottom of a table view controller or adding table view to a tab bar controller would be appreciated.

[image: wireframe]
[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Tab Bar Controller to storyboard, then do a right mouse button click on it and drag on your Table View Controller. On appeared menu select "View Controllers"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQRsZ.png)